# Mysql joining two tables in one

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I need to join two tables(Child and Parent/Carer) in one, listing first_name, last_name of Child in one column, and pc_title, pc_fname, pc_lname, pc_phone in another column.
What would be the query? Thank you.

Comment: Care to give us the structure of the table? And I think what you're looking for is a JOIN (LEFT, RIGHT, INNER, etc. depending on what you're going for)

Comment: and why the requirement to return the data in only two columns?  just list them all out in the select clause..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details of your schema and specific desired results, this is just a rough guestimate

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(' ',c.first_name,c.last_name) AS child_name,  
    CONCAT_WS(' ',pc.pc_title, pc.pc_fname, pc.pc_lname, pc.pc_phone) AS parent_carer_details
FROM Child c INNER JOIN Parent_Carer pc ON c.pc_id=pc.pc_id 
ORDER BY child_fname
```

That assumes that `pc_id` is a field in the child table, and the primary/identifying key in the parent/carer table is also named`pc_id`.

If you supply the schema, the edges can easily be roughed out.

Comment: You can specify the INNER JOIN condition in the FROM clause or in WHERE clause -- the MySQL query parser will take care of it, so they are effectively the same thing.  It's easiest to read in the FROM clause though.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, thats actually the case that the pc_id is in Child Table as Foreign key, and pc_id is Primary key in Parent/Carer Table. And if im right then it is possible to join tables just With FROM clause. Like: FROM Child, Parent/Carer ORDER BY child_fname

Comment: Make sure you specify your join clause, i.e. 'ON c.pc_id=pc.pc_id', but yes, you can ORDER on a generated column such as `child_name`.